# How to send EVENTS in addition to pageviews using a Java Script GTM tag which is tracking Individual Logged in Users using Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions

I have used a JavaScript tag which is tracking Individual Logged in Users using Google Analytics. It has a statement "ga('send', 'pageview');", which results in showing the pages a particular user has viewed, in user explorer of Google Analytics. I want to send events (I have already created in GTM) along with pageviews with reference to User-ID i.e., shKey in my case.

Here is the code in my JS tag;

```
 <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x' , 'auto');
    ga('set', 'userId', arguments.shKey);
    ga('set', 'dimension1', arguments.fname);
    ga('set', 'dimension2', arguments.type);
    ga('send', 'pageview'); 
    ga('send', 'event');
    </script>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you are violating Google's terms of service by storing email addresses and other personal information - you need at least to hash it with sha256 or better. Even so, you would be in violation of the GDPR in Europe, the California Consumer Privacy Act and the upcoming Chinese privacy law (just mentioning, if your legislation has no similar laws and you do not server customers from those countries, this won't be a problem).

Comment: Now I am using custom numeric ID as a unique identifier for a user, hence not voilating any privacy laws.  Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your ga('send', 'event') has a wrong signature. Events require category and action. So your event should look something like: ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label');
2. You're doing it strategically wrong. You're solving through JS what is supposed to be solved via GTM UI. In short term, it may seem easier and more elegant to do it in JS. In long term, however, it makes GTM obsolete and increases your technical debt, so the implementation becomes really difficult to maintain.

Comment: I have created a custom dimension which takes numeric ID as a unique identifier in place of email, hence not voilating any privacy laws. Thanks for pointing out. 
I have already created events using GTM, all I want now is to pass only those events to google analytics which are triggered by a user, not all events.

Answer (score 0):

**You have 2 issues: your code won't send an event (you're missing parameters), and you need to address PII (see further below)**

This is how you send an event programmatically:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

```
ga('send', 'event', 'My Category', 'My Action', 'My Label');
```

However if you're using GTM, you might want to look into how to handle events with GTM:
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide

```
// You need to configure GTM UI to handle below event as desired
dataLayer.push({'event': 'event_name'});
```

**Regarding PII, this is the authoritative answer from Google**:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en

> Google policies mandate that **no data be passed to Google that Google
> could use or recognize as personally identifiable information (PII)**.
> PII includes, but is not limited to, information such as email
> addresses, personal mobile numbers, and social security numbers

If you want to use PII, it must be encrypted before being sent, from same link as above:

> You can send Google Analytics an encrypted identifier or custom
> dimension that is based on PII, **as long as you use the proper
> encryption level. Google has a minimum hashing requirement of SHA256**

On top of that there might be additional legal restrictions depending on the jurisdiction you and your customers are in (eg in Europe you would have GDPR).